# How to extract Value of a class based on the color of adjacent div?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I am working on a webscrapping project. Have difficulty getting the text of an element with green progress bar. I have attached the html for your reference. I need the progress bar title if adjacent progress bar color is green.

```html
<div class="progressbar-warp">
  <span class="progressbar-title">
                                                ATTLIST
                                            </span>
  <div class="progressbar">
    <div data-percent="]\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'kj;hb p7-yh " class="progressbar-percent" style="background-color: green; width: 100%;">
    </div>
  </div>
  <span class="progressbar-title">
                                                None of the mentioned
                                            </span>
  <div class="progressbar">
    <div data-percent="100" class="progressbar-percent" style="width: 100%;">
    </div>
  </div>
  <span class="progressbar-title">
                                                XML
                                            </span>
  <div class="progressbar">
    <div data-percent="100" class="progressbar-percent" style="width: 100%;">
    </div>
  </div>
  <span class="progressbar-title">
                                                SGML
                                            </span>
  <div class="progressbar">
    <div data-percent="100" class="progressbar-percent" style="width: 100%;">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear - you say you "need the progress bar title": what exactly is the "progress bar title" in the sample html in your question?

Comment: In the above HTML example, 'ATTLIST' is what I want, the next div contains a green coloured progress bar.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of ways of accomplishing what you want. I personally prefer using lxml to parse the html, then use xpath to find the "green" `div` and locate the preceding `span` with the title:

```
import lxml.html as lh
prog = """[your html sample above]"""
doc = lh.fromstring(prog)
print(doc.xpath('//div[@class="progressbar"][./div[contains(@style,"green")]]/preceding-sibling::span/text()')[0].strip())
```

Output:

```
ATTLIST
```

Comment: AttributeError at line 94 of Examine.py: ResultSet object has no attribute 'xpath'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()? throwing above exception

Comment: @SeemaC It seems you're not using lxml but ElementTree or maybe BeautifulSoup. Try it with lxml as indicated in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
x = (
    soup.select_one('.progressbar-percent[style*="green"]')
    .find_previous(class_="progressbar-title")
    .text.strip()
)
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
ATTLIST
```

---

Or with pure CSS selector:

```py
x = soup.select_one(
    '.progressbar-title:has(+.progressbar:has([style*="green"]))'
).text.strip()
print(x)
```